# using fpdf, fpdi and fpdm to create pdf file with dynamically pagecount

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

i´m trying to create a pdf file with flexible length.
considering a template file with one page, having diffent form fields to be filled via php. this file has space for exactly ten database entries. so if i have a query with ten or less results, all works nicely and the form fields get filled correctly. now considering i have more than 10 entries, i need to add that template file multiple times and fill it with my values. and this is where i'm stuck: i cant achieve to genereate a pdf file with multiple pages, each page using the same template file, and fill it's form fields. i'm using fpdf.php, fpdm.php for merging / filling the form fields and fpdi to create pdf files with multiple page. as i said, filling one page works, but i fail at inserting another fillable template file to my document.

Comment: [FPDI will not handle dynamic content like form fields](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/after-importing-a-page-all-form-fields-are-gone/#question-85).

Comment: yes, thats the problem. creating a document with n pages, containing form fields.